# My class is calling a non-existing class?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using:

- Ruby 1.9.2
- Rails 3.1.10

This is my code:

```
class Report::ExpectedHour

  def initialize(user, options = {})
    @user       = user
    @date_start = options[:start]
    @date_end   = options[:end]
  end

  def expected_hours_range
    previous    = ExpectedHour.previous_dates(@user, @date_start).first
    hours_range = ExpectedHour.between_dates(@user, @date_start, @date_end)

    unless hours_range.include?(previous)
      hours_range << previous
    end

    hours_range
  end

end
```

Every time I call `expected_hours_range` from my instance I get this error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Report::ExpectedHour::ExpectedHour
from /home/edelpero/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@titi/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3/extensions.rb:206:in `const_missing_from_s3_library'
from /opt/lampp/htdocs/titi/app/models/report/expected_hour.rb:10:in `expected_hours_range'
```

I'm not sure why `Report::ExpectedHour::ExpectedHour` is called because I'm calling `ExpectedHour` which is an actual existing ActiveRecord class. Also `Report::ExpectedHour::ExpectedHour` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling classes inside your class methods, ruby expects it to be either a class nested inside you class itself or a constant. Try this:

```
class MyClass
  def some_method
    use_external_class = ::ExternalClass::CONSTANTB.bla
    # Use the '::'
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you Dave Newton and nicooga for your explanation, it worked like perfectly. I have another question. So why inside my ActiveRecord class I dont need to use :: when calling another model? Thanks again both.

Comment: Don't ask another question in your comment. Search Stack Overflow for the answer, and, if it doesn't show up, create a new question for that particular thing.